# Trying to integrate elasticsearch into gitlab, create_empty_index fails

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to use the elasticsearch tool for our gitlab repository. I follow [this guide](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/elasticsearch.html#adding-gitlab-39-s-data-to-the-elasticsearch-index) to integrate the gitlab data to the elastic search index, however I already fail at the first step. Executing

> gitlab-rake gitlab:elastic:create_empty_index --trace

results in this error:

```
** Invoke gitlab:elastic:create_empty_index (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute gitlab:elastic:create_empty_index
rake aborted!
Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::BadRequest: [400] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Failed to parse value [1] as only [true] or [false] are allowed."}],"type,"reason":"Failed to parse value [1] as only [true] or [false] are allowed."},"status":400}
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-5.0.3/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:201:in `__raise_transport_error'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-5.0.3/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:318:in `perform_request'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-5.0.3/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/http/faraday.rb:20:in `perform_request'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-5.0.3/lib/elasticsearch/transport/client.rb:131:in `perform_request'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/elasticsearch-api-5.0.3/lib/elasticsearch/api/namespace/common.rb:21:in `perform_request'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/elasticsearch-api-5.0.3/lib/elasticsearch/api/actions/indices/create.rb:86:in `create'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/elastic/helper.rb:29:in `create_empty_index'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/elastic.rake:95:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:251:in `block in execute'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:251:in `each'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:251:in `execute'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:181:in `invoke'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:153:in `invoke_task'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:109:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:109:in `each'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:109:in `block in top_level'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:118:in `run_with_threads'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:103:in `top_level'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:81:in `block in run'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:179:in `standard_exception_handling'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `run'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/rake:23:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:27:in `run'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:332:in `exec'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:20:in `dispatch'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:11:in `start'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/exe/bundle:34:in `block in <top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:100:in `with_friendly_errors'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/exe/bundle:26:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => gitlab:elastic:create_empty_index
```

How can I resolve this issue? Why can't `1` be parsed to `true` (or `false`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I tried integrating Elasticsearch Version 6.1.1 into Gitlab Version 10, which isn't compatible, which is also mentioned in the very link I provided:

> Elasticsearch 6.0+ is not supported currently. We will support 6.0+ in the future.

So, I installed Elasticsearch 5.5 and the integration worked fine.